# Call Webservices from HTML, Not able to receive the API response

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Please find the below Coding screen shot for Webservice:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJASG.jpg)
Postman screen shot:
[Postman screen shot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r36wu.jpg)

Here is the HTML calling the webservice:
[Here is the HTML calling the webservice:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNXMF.jpg)

Html Response:
[Html Response:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UBfY.jpg)

Please help me how to retrieve the response data from HTML page.

Read the response data from API and into DDL list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).

Comment: do yourself a favour by moving on to a modern web framework like react or blazor. save yourself a load of future headaches